# Facebook messenger android

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there anyway to somehow save, store messages if you only have Facebook messenger and not facebook account? I would like to have these conversations, and maybe search in some of them, making statistics, but there is no easy or right now I do not see any way for this.

Comment: How you want to save those things in messenger? Does it delete your messages if you log out or removes your messenger ? Please add more words specifically describing your question.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve it in the end... Facebook can generate your history in JSON format even for mobile accounts.